# Subject-verb agreement with more than one gerund in the subject

Tags: verb-agreement

I have seen a discussion of double gerunds and subject-verb agreement, but not addressing the following specific situtation:

"Reading and studying history HAS or HAVE been formative...": two gerunds with the same object as the subject of the sentence. I think a singular verb is clearly called for. Arguments in favor or against?

Answer (score 3):

It depends entirely on context and whether or not you are using the two things individually or referring to a single collective thing.

The sentence you provided is ambiguous but you can make the meaning clear (either way) by slightly rephrasing it.

For instance:

> Both reading and studying history **have** been formative.
>   The activity of reading and studying history **has** been formative.

---

Without rephrasing it, an argument could be made for either the singular or the plural. It depends on what you're trying to express. Neither would necessarily be wrong.